# Ionic 3 TypeScript Error - Json function not supported

Tags: json, typescript, ionic-framework, httpclient, httpmodule

I have created a service with the following line of code in my ionic 3 project
However i am getting the following json not supported error

[image: ERROR TypeError: res.json is not a function]

[image]

The Following is the snapshot of all the imported modules in my app.module.ts
Just to show that all the required modules are present

[image]

Not sure why this error is displayed. Can some one please advise?
Please let me know if any additional info required.

Comment: Are you sure that your response is json?

Comment: Yes , i have fetched the entire dynamically generated URL within http.get  and tested it in the browser , it does return json data

Comment: If its already returning json then why are you using res.json()? Just use res